# "firebase serve" in firebase functions is not running the latest changes

Tags: node.js, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

I am playing with firebase functions. Works fine when deploying to firebase server using command `firebase deploy --only functions`. However, I would like to test my functions locally before deploy to server of course. What I see running firebase serve is that the functions "deployed" locally have not the latest changes I did in indext.ts - are running the last builded version, which are in index.js.

My question is, How do I manual build my firebase functions project to test them locally with latest changes?
Should `firebase serve` autobuild the project before deploy it locally? For me, it sounds like a bug.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

If you want to reload the changes to your TypeScript when running `firebase serve` or `firebase functions:shell`, all you have to do is build your project again using npm script that was created for you when you initialized the project (see package.json):

```
cd functions
npm run build
```

This will transpile your TypeScript to JavaScript, and the changes to the JavaScript will get picked up by the emulator automatically.

Also, if you are a more advanced TypeScript user, you can run `tsc --watch` to automatically compile TS to JS when source files change on disk.  You can read more about that [in this blog](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2018/01/streamline-typescript-development-cloud-functions.html).

Comment: Thanks Doug!! Working now.

Definitly, this is what I was looking for!. I tried with `npm run build`, but I missed to run `cd functions` before.

Comment: And you have to build everytime?

Comment: Or you could just put this as your npm "serve" script: `"serve": "npm run build && firebase emulators:start --only functions & tsc --watch"`. (Note the addition of `& tsc --watch` at the end.

Comment: @Matthcw did you test that? It doesn't work for me with a new `firebase init` project. This command `firebase emulators:start --only functions` is still active so `tsc --watch` never gets executed. I have tried `&` and `&&` in front of `tsc --watch`. So far I've found that I need to open a new terminal and run `tsc --watch` in some manner.

Comment: @Ash It might be your OS and choice-of-terminal. I'm using macOS Mojave v10.14.6 and Terminal. The use of single `&` works fine for me. I learned this from here: https://bashitout.com/2013/05/18/Ampersands-on-the-command-line.html

Comment: @Matthcw of course, that makes sense as I'm on Windows. OS was the key part as per that article; `This trailing ampersand directs the shell to run the command in the background, that is, it is forked and run in a separate sub-shell, as a job, asynchronously.` and `A single ampersand & can also delimit a list of commands to be run asynchronously`

Comment: @Matthcw your first comment is _exactly_ what i was looking for. Wasn't getting graceful emulator shutdowns when the ts app crashed. For anyone worried about background process shutdown, ```^C``` will do it. I verified using ```ps -A``` output before and after ```^C```

Answer (score 8):

`firebase serve` doesn't seem to be running `npm build`. But if you look inside `functions/package.json`, you can see there is already a `serve` script there that performs `npm run build && firebase serve --only functions`. So if you just do:

```
cd functions
npm run serve
```

You can build and serve without having to do two separate commands.

Answer (score 4):

If you are looking for hot reloading i just did it like below:

```
"start:emulators": "firebase emulators:start --only functions",
"ts:watch": "tsc --watch",
"dev": "concurrently --kill-others \"npm run start:emulators\" \"npm run ts:watch\"",
```

It will run both firebase and ts watch in parallel, which will help your development speed

Comment: To use the above requires installing the npm `concurrently` pacakage.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can just switch between Javascript and Typescript in an initialized project. The setup for Typescript is a bit different than Javascript. You will need to migrate your Javascript project to Typescript.

To migrate your project from JS to TS follow this firebase-functions documentation on :

[Migrating an existing JavaScript Cloud Functions project](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/typescript#migrating_an_existing_javascript_project_to_typescript)

Typescript project setup:

[image: Typescript project setup]

Comment: The transpilation process is performed by firebase cli when I execute "firebase deploy", but not when I execute "firebase serve" to run the functions locally. So, I understand, there should be a manual build for that, or do it automatically when "firebase serve" command is executed.

Comment: 'firebase serve' sometime doesn't hot reload changes and instead uses cache data. have you tried clearing browser window cache or re-serving the command.

Comment: It is not related to browser. I can see the old version of index.js in IDE.

Comment: don't know dude. just wait for a better answer. meanwhile, you can backup your project and try migration if you like. no harm done :)

Answer (score 1):

Go to functions folder, open `package.json` and add new key:   `"hotReload": "tsc --watch"`

next, run `npm run hotReload` in same functions folder and keep the terminal open. This will update `*.js` whenever any changes to `*.ts` file. Remember that cloud functions run from `*.js` file not `*.ts` file. Hence, *.ts file needs to compiled to `*.js` first.

Next, open new terminal, go to main project folder and run `firebase serve` (to parallely run hosting+functions) or `firebase serve --only functions`

Answer (score -1):

Just use this command when you are using first time npm serve command

```
firebase emulators:start
```